# Redirecting in ASP.NET MVC with parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following code but it doesn't seem to redirect to my action with the given parameter.  I have redirected something similar but the parameters were query string parameters.  I'm wondering if it is done another way for parameters since the following doesn't work or what I might be doing wrong in my call to the action?

```
public ActionResult PassThrough (long i)
{
   return RedirectToAction("RedirectAction", new { d = i});
}

public ActionResult RedirectAction (long d)
{
   return SomeView();
}
```

Comment: What exactly does **not** work? Does the client not get redirected to the other action or does the parameter you pass not get sent in to the action? If it is the latter, does it work on its own anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the redirection command as result:

```
public ActionResult PassThrough (long i)
{
    return RedirectToAction("RedirectAction", new { d = i});
}
```

Comment: Haha... didn't we just have this question?

Comment: @womp: Dunno, I just came out of the bath.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to add the return but it is there.  i did a search and didn't find the question you were talking about.  can you give me a link?